# Multi-tenant WebSocket microservice based on String

Tags: spring, spring-security, websocket, spring-websocket

#### Disclaimer

Following code **works**, I would only ask about approach and grab some feedback about general idea, because it's my first time with Spring WebSockets + Spring Security for WebSockets.

In the Internet there is not much valuable articles about connecting all pieces into one, working solution.

I working with the latest Spring Boot (3.1.x).

#### Requirements

The concept is super simple. One microservice (multi-tenant) which will be handling WebSocket connections. Let's assume we have couple of the clients, each of them has numerous users.

```
client-A
  - user-1
  - user-2
client-B
  - user-1
  - user-2
  - user-3
client-C
  - user-1
client-<N>
  - user-1
  - user-2
  ...
  - user-<M>
```

Users will be connecting from SPA written in the React. Each of the connection must be secured by a valid token (not JWT). This microservice will be running in the Kubernetes cluster, so state of subscribed WebSocket connections (users) should be shared between instances. RabbitMQ should be a back-end message broker.

#### Code

`WebSocketConfiguration`

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
@Order(HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE + 99)
public class WebSocketConfiguration implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry stompEndpointRegistry) {
        stompEndpointRegistry
                .addEndpoint("/ws")
                .setAllowedOriginPatterns("http://localhost:63342");
    }

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry messageBrokerRegistry) {
        messageBrokerRegistry
                .setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app")
                .enableSimpleBroker("/topic", "/queue");
    }

    @Override
    public void configureClientInboundChannel(ChannelRegistration registration) {
        registration.interceptors(new ChannelInterceptor() {
            @Override
            public Message<?> preSend(Message<?> message, MessageChannel channel) {
                StompHeaderAccessor accessor = getAccessor(message, StompHeaderAccessor.class);
                StompCommand actualStompCommand = accessor != null ? accessor.getCommand() : null;
                if (actualStompCommand == CONNECT) {
                    String authorizationHeader = accessor.getFirstNativeHeader("Authorization");
                    String tokenType = "Bearer" + SPACE;

                    if (isBlank(authorizationHeader) || !authorizationHeader.startsWith(tokenType)) {
                        throw new AccessDeniedException("Authorization header not found");
                    }

                    String clientHeader = accessor.getFirstNativeHeader("X-Client");
                    if (isBlank(clientHeader) || !clientHeader.startsWith("valid")) {
                        throw new AccessDeniedException("Client not exists");
                    }

                    String token = authorizationHeader.substring(tokenType.length());
                    if (!token.startsWith("valid")) {
                        throw new AccessDeniedException("Token is not valid");
                    }

                    String userIdHeader = accessor.getFirstNativeHeader("X-User-Id");
                    if (isBlank(userIdHeader)) {
                        throw new AccessDeniedException("UserId not found");
                    }

                    PrincipalId principalId = new PrincipalId(clientHeader, userIdHeader); // this is a simple record
                    Set<SimpleGrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities = singleton(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("USER"));
                    Authentication user = new PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken(principalId, token, grantedAuthorities);

                    accessor.setUser(user);
                }
                return message;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Questions:

1. Can I do authorization in a another (better?) way?
2. There is something missing from the Spring Security point of view? (`AuthorizationManager`, `Authentication` or something else)

---

`IncomingMessagesController`

```
@Controller
public class IncomingMessagesController {
    private static final Logger logger = getLogger(IncomingMessagesController.class);

    private final SimpMessagingTemplate simpMessagingTemplate;
    private final SimpUserRegistry simpUserRegistry;

    public IncomingMessagesController(SimpMessagingTemplate simpMessagingTemplate, SimpUserRegistry simpUserRegistry) {
        this.simpMessagingTemplate = simpMessagingTemplate;
        this.simpUserRegistry = simpUserRegistry;
    }

    @PostMapping("/api/private-incoming-messages/{client}")
    public void privateIncomingMessageClient(@PathVariable("client") String client, @RequestBody MessageTO messageTO) {
        logger.info("privateIncomingMessageClient client={}", client);

        List<PrincipalId> principalIds = simpUserRegistry
                .getUsers()
                .stream()
                .map(simpUser -> (PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken) simpUser.getPrincipal())
                .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                .map(preAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken -> (PrincipalId) preAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken.getPrincipal())
                .filter(principalId -> principalId.client().equals(client))
                .toList();

        for (PrincipalId principalId : principalIds) {
            String body = messageTO.getBody();
            DecoratedMessageTO decoratedMessageTO = new DecoratedMessageTO()
                    .setOriginalBody(body)
                    .setDecoratedBody("### [PRIVATE] %s ###".formatted(body));
            simpMessagingTemplate.convertAndSendToUser(principalId.toString(), "/topic/private-msg", decoratedMessageTO);
        }
    }

    @PostMapping("/api/private-incoming-messages/{client}/{userId}")
    public void privateIncomingMessage(
            @PathVariable("client") String client,
            @PathVariable("userId") String userId,
            @RequestBody MessageTO messageTO
    ) {
        logger.info("privateIncomingMessage client={}, userId={}", client, userId);

        String body = messageTO.getBody();
        DecoratedMessageTO decoratedMessageTO = new DecoratedMessageTO()
                .setOriginalBody(body)
                .setDecoratedBody("### [PRIVATE] %s ###".formatted(body));
        simpMessagingTemplate.convertAndSendToUser(new PrincipalId(client, userId).toString(), "/topic/private-msg", decoratedMessageTO);
    }
}
```

Questions:

1. Is it good way to send messages to single user for client (eg. client-B:user-2)?
2. Is it effective way to look for the client users filtering whole list of the subscribers? (number of active subscriptions could be about 10k) Maybe I need some optimization here?

If there is needed some more details let me know.